# Display an overlay iframe with content from dynamic url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to achieve similar effect as this website has: http://www.dubstep.net 
 if you click play or title on any of the players, you will see a window appear, with an overlay effect. Such windows is iframe. From looking at page source I can understand that `data-id=""` attribute is responsible for what is shown in the iframe. I just can't figure out how though. what happens when users click that play button? and how is data-id attribute used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fairly simple process. They pre-built HTML responses into requests to `www.dubstep.com/track/trackNumber`, where `trackNumber` is a parameter. So on the server side, there is a `RewriteRule` defined in `nginx`(they are using `nginx` as a server, judging by the `curl -V` "fingerprint").

So basically `www.dubstep.com/track/4567` is equivalent to `www.dubstep.com/track/index.php?trackNumber=4567`.

Now an `iframe` is a way to load and display an external page. The way they do it is similar to this idea:

```
$('.track').click(function(event) {// assuming track divs have class .track.
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = "//www.dubstep.com/track/" + event.target.getAttribute("data-id");// this uses the data-id attribute of the clicked item.
    iframe.height = // some computed height;
    iframe.width = // some computed width;
    iframe.name = "whatever";
    iframe.style.display = "none;"
    // or
    iframe.style.visibility = "hidden";

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iframe); // element is inserted somewhere in the DOM.
    // Now some form of transition is applied.
    });
```

The `iframe` is wrapped inside the two modal `div` elements, for display purposes.

Comment: will appendChild set display to block or visibility to visible?

Answer (score 0):

iFrames load external pages.  All that data is being pulled from a .html (or equivalent) page.  The use of the data-id attribute wont tell you much as it is most certainly handled server-side as a means to collect and display only certain tracks or whatever (in other words, that wont tell you much about the website listed and how it works).

Read up about frames:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery colorbox. It is pretty cool!

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

After that include your script location and css file

```
<script src="colorbox_folder/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox_folder/colorbox.css" />

 <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="callingIframe()">Go to Google</a>
```

This is javascript function

```
function callingIframe()
{
  $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true,onClosed:function(){ location.reload(true); },             width:"940", height:"650"});
}
```